# How to get the buttons to the left side?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create the buttons using `tkinter`.

Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk

def pressed():
    print("button pressed!")

def create_layout(frame):

    frame.pack(fill=None,expand=True)
    mycolor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (250, 250, 210)
    root.configure(bg=mycolor)
    bottomframe = tk.Frame(root)
    bottomframe.pack( side = tk.LEFT )

    button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button1", fg="black",command=pressed,anchor="w")
    button1.pack( side = tk.LEFT)

    button2 =tk.Button(frame, text="Button2", fg="black",command=pressed,anchor="w")
    button2.pack( side = tk.LEFT )



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("250x150")
frame = tk.Frame(root)
create_layout(frame)
root.mainloop()
```

I have specified the anchor="w", and side="LEFT", but it does not seem to be work.

Output of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `frame.pack(fill=None,expand=True)` to `frame.pack(fill=None,expand=True, anchor="w")` will align the buttons to the left side.